How to run multiple tests in parallel with colcon test?
I am currently engaged in a ROS2 project aimed at optimizing our testing processes by enabling concurrent execution of tests within a single package using colcon test.
Initially, I attempted to utilize the --parallel-workers flag. However, this approach did not resolve the issue as intended. It facilitates parallel execution across multiple packages, but intra-package test execution remains sequential.
Each test is implemented using the launch_testing framework and integrated into colcon via the add_launch_test macro within the CMakeLists.txt file.
Key specifics include:

ROS2 version: Humble
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Test execution command: colcon test

I am seeking guidance or practical examples that outline best practices for achieving concurrent test execution at the ROS2 package level.
Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I received an answered on GitHub. I am quoting it here for future reference:

For parallel builds, colcon currently relies on system load tracking
in GNU Make to parallelize compilation within each concurrently
building CMake package. Though CTest is able to run tests in parallel,
it doesn't have the same load tracking parallelization feature that
GNU Make does.
To work around this, you could pass --ctest-args -j <NUMBER_OF_WORKERS> to your colcon test invocations, but you should
be careful. Many of the tests written for the ROS 2 core packages were
not implemented with parallelization in mind and my fail. That doesn't
mean you shouldn't write parallelizable tests in your packages, of
course.
This story may improve a little bit when we get a GNU job server
implemented for colcon-parallel-executor, at which point CTest will be
able to borrow job slots from the executor when it want to run
parallel tests, but we will probably need to set up a way to "opt-in"
packages to parallel testing.

